# Can not show the image by image_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a very simple rails program to show a picture and here is my `show.html.erb` file

```
<div class="row">  <div class="col m12">
<div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
  <div class="card-content white-text">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col m4 center">
      <%= image_tag "courses/#{@course.image}" %>    
      </div>
      <div class="col m8">
      <span class="card-title"><%= @course.title %></span> 
      <p><%= @course.description %></p>         
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> </div></div></div>
```

What I want is, for example, in the folder courses, there are 4 images 1 2 3 4, when I connect to the `http://localhost:3000/courses/2`, it will show the picture 2, but it gave me this problem `The asset "courses/image" is not present in the asset pipeline.`

I am very confusing am tried to fixed it but could not. I am a newbie and still stydying, could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: Check around 2.2 in the docs here. I think you need to set up the initializer for assets https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Does it work in development and not in production? Is the image located in `app/assets/images/courses`?  Which rails version are you using?

Comment: @nathanvda : yeah the image located in `app/assets/images/courses` , and my rails version is 6.0.1

Comment: The error says `courses/image` so is there an image called `image`? Should it not at 
 least end in `jpg/png`  ?

Comment: @nathanvda In my folder `app/assets/images/courses` there are only four images named 1 2 3 4, when I change the line `<%= image_tag "courses/#{@course.image}" %>` into this `<%= image_tag "courses/1.png", class: "img-responsive"% >`, it showed the image 1, but only the image 1.

Comment: you will need to link to each image

Comment: are you sure about `@course.image` is right path or filename ?

Comment: @7urkm3n thanks for your comment, I just thought that `@course.image` is the path of the images

Comment: @anhbuiask you did not think critically. It will contain whatever was saved in it. You can output it to see what it contains. The way you are using it, it must contain `"1.png" or "n.png" # n being any number 1 to 4`. That is not done well. If you saved it yourself, then change it according to my answer. If you can't change that, then change your image_tag string argument to be able to accept it accordingly. See my answer for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

What you need in different ways is:

```
  <%= image_tag "courses/1.png" %>
  <%= image_tag "courses/2.png" %>
  <%= image_tag "courses/3.png" %>
  <%= image_tag "courses/4.png" %>
```

So, you should do one of these:

- Try saving full path_name (after images directory) for every course i.e.

```
  @course.image = "courses/n.png" # where n is any name for the image for that course
  # then:
  <%= image_tag @course.image %>
```

- Just save the number in `@course.image` but use the path like you are already doing:

```
  @course.image = n
  <%= image_tag "course/#{@course.image}.png" %>
```

First one is the standard way of course. Your `@course.image` should have the complete path in it. `image_tag` is expecting a string which will be a path and your `@course.image` should be having it, instead of you writing a part of it yourself. Remember, that file extension is a "part" of the path so you should not ignore it.

**Hint:** You can add size of the image too in this tag. It is very helpful:

```
  <%= image_tag @course.image, size: "100x100" %>
```

Comment: For further understanding you can always learn more from apidock: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag